# How to find out a given string in a line using java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want find a Given sting in a line.For this I have wrote the code.I use the Pattern class to find the whether the give string is available in a line or not.It is gives the lines,those are not have given string.I want the lines those have the given string.Please check it my code.

Code:

```
 public class StringMatch {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String text="dsfhgs the dgfre fh" +
                "hjfgeh fhg hghjr" +
                "fhvhjf the vgh fhjghf" +
                "fbvhjfd  fhvfg fjvhf" +
                "the hfdvhjf vhf  fhdvjfd" +
                "hfvbhd thehjdvhj hdfvhdf";
    String pattern = ".*?\\the\\b.*?";
    String f="C:\\TextFiles\\sample.txt";
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    while(br.readLine()!=null) {
        line=br.readLine();
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please run the above code.What it shows. sample.txt file contains the text.I initialize that text in String variable text for understand what is in file.Please check it my task.Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does my answer below works for you?

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    String given = "dsfhgs the dgfre fh \n" +
            "hjfgeh fhg hghjr \n" +
            "fhvhjf the vgh fhjghf \n" +
            "fbvhjfd  fhvfg fjvhf \n" +
            "the hfdvhjf vhf  fhdvjfd \n" +
            "hfvbhd thehjdvhj hdfvhdf." ;
    String[] lines = given.split("\n");
    String searchStr = "the";       
     for(String line : lines)
     {

         String[] wordOfLine = line.split(" ");
         boolean match = false;
         for(String word : wordOfLine)
         {
                if (searchStr.equals(word)) 
                {
                    match = true;
                } 
         }

         if(match)
         {
             System.out.println("Found value: " + searchStr);
         }
         else 
         {
             System.out.println("NO MATCH");
         }

    }


}
```

Comment: It's okay.But,It find out the sub string of that given string also.for example in line 6 of my input.I want find out the exact string only.Thank you for Reply.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my code and it prints excact search string. Does it what you want?

Comment: Okay it's fine.If Search string comes from another textField entered by user.How can I give for that situation.For example searchStr=textField.getText();

Comment: It is also shows the 6th line is true.But,6th line is not has the exact "the".

Comment: hmm ok i think i had misunderstand ur comment previously. I had updated again. Does it match what you want?

Answer (score 1):

or you should use [String Contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
String test="demo string";
System.out.println(test.contains("demo"));
```

This will then return true or false

If you dont care about case you will have to do

```
System.out.println(test.toLowerCase().contains(new String("demo").toLowerCase()));
```

contains is case sensitive

It wont do any fancy regex though just a simple check for comparison

Edit

```
String str = new String("demo");
if (test.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: It displays non given string statements.

Comment: ok try and use your brain a bit here. It's not hard to go a bit further. Ive added an edit to should you how to print out what is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it following way:

```
String test="demo string";
System.out.println(test.indexOf("demo"));
```

**Output :**

```
0
```

Note: `indexOf()` will return the position of first character if it finds a string, else `-1` is returned. Alternatively you can use `Regular Expressions` to search complex strings as well.

`Using Regular Expressions :`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("23asd56");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**Output :**

```
2
3
5
6
```

Comment: I want to find out the exact string not a sub string.

Comment: You can search term accordingly, anyway look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
while(m.find()){
//print m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that (unlike most other languages) in java, `matches()` must match the *whole* string to be true, so add `".*"` to each end of the pattern.

Because you have newline chars in your input, you also need to add `(?s)` to turn on the DOTALL flag, which causes the dot to match newlines too:

```
boolean b = Pattern.matches("(?s).*\\b"+searchStr+"\\b.*", line);
```

Comment: It is also displays the lines of not present the given search string.Same as my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this pattern as below  simple!!!!!:

```
String pattern = ".*?\\the\\b.*?";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```

I Hope this will help you

Comment: It shows no Match.But the text have "the".I have post my input code also as above.

Comment: `.*?` is a bit confusing - just `.*` will match the same input.

Answer (score 0):

```
text.split("\n")).filter(line -> line.contains("the")).forEach(value -> System.out.println("Found value: " + value));
```